# Why is my element not being deleted using jQuery.remove?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to remove an element with all of its children, too. This element is a file representation sort-of-thing and all of them get an unique ID.

Here's the PHP code that generates them:

```
<a id="custom-my-files-file-<?= $i; ?>" href="<?= $data_url ?>" target="_blank"><div class="custom-my-files-list-file">
    <p class="custom-my-files-list-info custom-my-files-list-info-type"><?= $data_type ?></p>
    <p class="custom-my-files-list-info custom-my-files-list-info-name"><?= $data_name ?></p>
    <a><i class="custom-my-files-list-trash icon-trash" data-element="custom-my-files-file-<?= $i; ?>" data-userid="<?= $myself->ID; ?>" data-fileid="<?= $i; ?>"></i></a>
</div></a>
```

I'm trying to remove the a element wrapping the whole thing. Here's the code I'm using to try and do that:

```
var the_element = '#' + $(this).data('element');
var elem_object = $(the_element);

if (elem_object.length) {
    elem_object.remove();
    console.log('deleted element:');
}
```

Nothing happens when the code is ran and 'deleted element' does appear in the console.

EDIT:

Okay, the JavaScript code is within a success function inside an AJAX call. The AJAX call is in a function `function do_file_trash_action()`. This function gets added to the elements like so: `$('.custom-my-files-list-trash').click(do_file_trash_action);`

Then, when I upload a file, I add the function to the last element: `$('.custom-my-files-list-trash').last().click(do_file_trash_action);`

I have verified that all of the elements are getting the callback by doing an `alert('Click');` inside of the function as a test.

And, lastly, the function itself is within:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

I also forgot to add that:
`var the_element = '#' + $(this).data('element');`
Is outside of the success function and inside the do_file_trash_action function. Logging it out, after fixing concatenation, it prints:
`#custom-my-files-file-0`

Comment: concatenation is done with `+`, not `.`

Comment: I changed it and it's still the same, tough...

Comment: @TarikDruskic then we need more context into how that logic is being invoked.

Comment: You need to provide more info. What's the context of `this`? Is the code running after the dom has loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put an "a" tag inside another "a" --> https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

I tried to replace your wrapping "a" with a div and it's working --> https://jsfiddle.net/p6to8e8o/12/

```
<div id="custom-my-files-file-1" href="#">
  <div class="custom-my-files-list-file">
    <p class="custom-my-files-list-info custom-my-files-list-info-type">$data_type</p>
    <p class="custom-my-files-list-info custom-my-files-list-info-name">$data_name</p>
    <a><i class="custom-my-files-list-trash icon-trash" data-element="custom-my-files-file-1" style="cursor: pointer;" data-fileid="1">TRASH</i></a>
  </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.custom-my-files-list-trash').click(do_file_trash_action);
});

function do_file_trash_action() {
  var the_element = '#' + $(this).data('element');
  var elem_object = $(the_element);

  if (elem_object.length) {
    elem_object.remove();
    console.log('deleted element:');
  }
}
```

You have to update your html structure.